# Бесконечный цикл при вводе символов

Tags: c++, циклы

Добрый день! Выполняя лабораторную работу по C++, наткнулся на такую вот проблему:

Имею я статичный метод `readCommand` который читает команду... И при успешном вводе передает данную команду к другому методу `choose(index)`...

Все работает, но есть такая проблема, при вводе цифр все хорошо, работает.. Но если случайно ввести **не цифру**, а символ или букву, цикл в методе будет бесконечно работать...

Вот код:

```
static void readCommand(){
    cout << endl <<"Select one: ";
    while(true){
        int index = 0;
        cin >> index;
        if(index < 1 || index > 4){
            cout << endl << "INDEX UNDEFINED!" << endl;
            cout << endl << "Select again: ";
        } else{
            choose(index);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот как работает программа:

[image: Пример работы программы]

Как это исправить? Как знаток Java, я знаю что можно легко этого избежать добавив обработчик исключений.. Только вот в C++ как это сделать, я не знаю..

Comment: Посмотрите на [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c).

Comment: @post_zeew неа, не помогло...

Comment: @post_zeew, если человек спрашивает *по русски*, то м.б. не стоит отправлять его на *англоязычный сайт*?

Comment: @avp не, все окей) Я нормально английский знаю)

Comment: @avp, Стоит. В данном случае можно и без знания (английского) языка понять предлагаемые варианты решения проблемы.

Comment: @post_zeew, хотя бы для себя честно ответьте на вопрос -- "а зачем Вы здесь"? Если не хотите помочь человеку -- просто пройдите мимо его вопроса.

Comment: @avp, Причем тут это? Если бы я не хотел помочь человеку – я бы прошел мимо. Далее разводить оффтоп смысла не вижу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим нам нужно прочитать целое число

```
int value;
std::cin >> value;
```

Если пользователь введет что-то не то, поток изменит свое состояние с [good](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) на [fail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/). Проверить это можно так:

```
int value;
std::cin >> value;
if(std::cin.fail()){
    //Как-то боремся с проблемой
}
```

Или боле короткая запись:

```
int value;
std::cin >> value;
if(!std::cin){
    //Как-то боремся с проблемой
}
```

Теперь как бороться с проблемой:

```
int value;
std::cin >> value;
if(!std::cin){
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //Выкидываем все что ввел пользователь до конца строки
    std::cin.clear();  //Убираем флаг ошибки. Теперь состояние потока снова good

}
```

На этом все. Добавьте такую проверку и все будет работать. Можно еще вывести сообщение об ошибке
http://cpp.sh/9by3m

Comment: Кстати помогло) Я оказывается не правильно его использовал...

Comment: У меня, кстати, вот это `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());` вообще не компилируется (даже с -std=c++14)

Comment: @avp `#include<limits>`

Comment: Все равно не работает. Циклится. Простой `cin.clear(); ... cin.get()` до `\n` работает, а с ignore циклится.

Comment: Ну я вносил в ответ правку. Там была ошибка с использованием `ingnore`. У меня в ответе ссылка на онлайн компилятор, там все работает.

Comment: Не читается что-то Ваша ссылка. Тут пример поправьте уж.

Comment: @avp, пример был исправлен когда я вам писал. Ссылку попробуйте открыть еще раз. Тот сайт иногда вырубается на несколько минут

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, опять не открывается. Да и в чате как раз намедни обсуждали такие же проблемы. Большинство за короткий (50-200 строк) код прямо в теле вопроса или ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что ввод `gg` это не число, которое ожидает `cin >> index`.

Эти символы остаются в потоке ввода и в цикле делается попытка 
повторно считать их же. Наверное простейшим способом будет чтение всех данные до конца строки перед повторной попыткой.

Учтите, что cin после обнаружения ошибки будет находиться в неработоспособном состоянии, из которого его надо выводить. Я, конечно, понимаю, что у Вас лаба по С++ (и даже сейчас посмотрю, как это делается в крестах), но искренне советую на практике использовать средства ввода-вывода из Си (это проще).

Вот пример, который работает (и обрабатывает EOF в т.ч. в состоянии ошибки ввода)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for (;;) {
    int v;
    cin >> v;
    if (!cin.good()) {
      if (cin.eof())
        cout << "eof\n";
      else {
        cout << "err\n";
        cin.clear();
        char c;
        while (cin.good() && (c = cin.get()) != '\n');
        if (cin.good()) {
          cout << "again\n";
          continue;
        } else {
          if (cin.eof())
            cout << "Eof\n";
          else
            cout << "Err\n";
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    } else
      cout << "v = " << v << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: У средств из Си, конечно, есть преимущества, но простота не входит в их число

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, не согласен. IO в Си (в отличии от крестов с кучей не очевидных деталей) очень просто.

Comment: C++ это не C. В некоторых ситуациях эти функции просто не применимы. Так же их сложно рефакторить, вместо того чтобы просто поменять в одном месте `int` на `float`, нужно просматривать весь код и менять строку формата в каждом вызове.

Comment: Плюс эти функции запрещено использовать [стандартом кодирования Apache](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Cpp_Coding_Standards/SECURITY/UnsafeFunc) из за проблем с безопасностью.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, в этом стандарте еще бы делением на 0 озаботились. Все надо делать с умом. То, что кресты это не Си, это очевидно. Большой вопрос, что и для чего лучше. Тут каждый сам для себя (и набираемой команды, кстати) решает. А сама постановка вопроса о рефакторинге (кстати, термин стал популярен с развитием ООП и в частности крестов) с заменой int на float уже о многом говорит.

Answer (score 2):

В C++ существует класс `stringstream`. Чтобы его использовать, необходимо добавить `#include <string>` и `#include <sstream>`.
Следующий код осуществляет безопасный ввод чисел с помощью своего потока.

```
int data;
string buffer = "";
cout << "Введите данные: " << endl;

while (true) 
{
    getline(cin, buffer);

    // Безопасный перевод из строки в число.
    stringstream myStream(buffer);
    if ( (myStream >> data) )
        break;
    cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите..." << endl;
}
```

Comment: и как он определит что пользователь ввел число? Парсить не надо в число?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT если в строке будет буква, то она и то, что после неё, будет исключена из ввода. Пример: вы ввели 5d2. в data будет только 5. Вы ввели d25. Будет предложено повторить ввод.

Comment: Ааа понятно) Возьму на заметку)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` для сброса буфера после неверного ввода...

Comment: Пробовал) Ругается непонятно на что))